# Will I be able to purchase an Arafat T-shirt in Palestine/Israel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, israel, prohibited-items, palestine

I will be visiting Israel and Palestine next month. Among the places I plan to visit are Bethlehem and Arafat's tomb in Ramallah. I plan to wear a T-shirt with Arafat's picture on it only during my visit to his tomb.

Will I be able to purchase such attire somewhere in Ramallah?

Comment: please mention your current passport-issuing country, religious and organizational affiliations. Depending on those info, the answers will vary very widely.

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: yep. Do you think that in Israel a Jewish middle-age person from USA will be treated same as a practicing young muslim from Egypt?

Comment: Why not buy one back home or online?

Comment: @JonathanReez I wanted to buy one online but worried about traveling with it. My profile is such that I expect to face extra scrutiny entering Israel, maybe including search of my luggage.

Comment: And why do you feel like traveling wearing it then? To troll the Israelis? Tho show support for Palestine?

Comment: just relevant and recent: https://twitter.com/AkshayaSays/status/834981881288458240

Comment: @JonathanReez Because I am an admirer. I hope that's good enough. I am not in the business of trolling anyone.

Comment: @pnuts +1and noted.

Comment: @kmonsoor: Will OP's nationality, religion, etc, really affect whether they are able to buy a shirt?  I can understand it might make a difference as to how they are treated when they wear it, but that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yasser Arafat Museum](http://www.yam.ps/en/)

[NPR](http://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2016/11/28/503172568/new-museum-examines-life-and-legacy-of-palestinian-leader-yasser-arafat) Article

> An image of his face — with his classic scruffy facial hair and
>   headdress — now adorns hats and **sweatshirts in the museum gift shop**.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen such shirts for sale in the Muslim Quater of the Old City of Jerusalem, but I have never been to Ramallah as I am a young religious Jew.